# como puedo operar cada dato que me da un char en c++

Tags: c++

Como puedo operar cada dato de este char es decir

que el texto[0] * 1, el texto [1] * 2....hasta texto [8]*9

prácticamente se ingresa un número y cada número lo separa, una vez separados se deben multiplicar como explique arriba.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
system("cls");

char texto[9];
int pos1, pos2, pos3, pos4, pos5, pos6, pos7, pos8, pos9;
 
    cout << "Introduce el codigo de grupo,editor y libro: ";
    cin >>  texto;
    cout << "codigo de grupo " << texto[0] << "\ncodigo de editor: " 
        << texto[1]<<texto[2]<<texto[3]<<texto[4]<<"\ncodigo de libro: "<<texto[5]<<texto[6]<<texto[7]<<texto[8] << endl;

    pos1 = texto[0] * 1;
    pos2 = texto[1] * 2;
    pos3 = texto[2] * 3;
    pos4 = texto[3] * 4;
    pos5 = texto[4] * 5;
    pos6 = texto[5] * 6;
    pos7 = texto[6] * 7;
    pos8 = texto[7] * 8;
    pos9 = texto[8] * 9;


system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

para no realizar 9 variables int pos1 ... pos9, puedes usar un vector "int pos[]"
y realizas un ciclo para realizar dichas operaciones quedaria de la siguiente forma

```
int pos[9]
for(int i = 0; i<9; i++){
    pos[i]=texto[i]*i+1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la función [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) de la cabecera [`<algorithm>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    char texto[9] {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
    int pos[9];

    std::transform(texto, texto + 9, pos, [n = 0](char c) mutable { return n++ * c; });

    for (const auto &valor : pos)
        std::cout << valor << ' ';

    return 0;
}
```

Esta función pasa elemento a elemento de una colección y lo guarda en otra colección tras aplicarle una función de transformación. El código anterior [genera la siguiente salida](https://tio.run/##bY3NisIwFIXXvU9xYGBspxV0aVt9EXGRiVEDaVKSGxkoffZOYoXZDNzF5fx8R47jVhph78vyoa008arQaxfYKzGc6E8T5u685kcSSVvGILQtK5qokA/hweqH3flwwbRv8P/NHRW5ObqQgh1REfjatuyFDTfnh/LFaFYUahyaHG1wtjhidylfO7LCEFl8G4UJXnH0Frau8QXZYa4yNbFQSmcDQ8RE@nwKk6Q20yoq1lXpIqPvsXrp2WCTy2/krqN5WX4B):

> ```
> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
> ```